# C++ If/of-stream. Значение ф-ии file.clear()

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

что именно делает ф-ия clear()? 
seekg - как я понял - перемещает "курсор" в позицию (0), то есть в начало строки, а clear что-то чистит?

```
    ifstream file("f.txt");
    while (file >> m)
    count++;
    file.clear();
    file.seekg(0);
```

Comment: А вы в справочник заглядывали?

Comment: Если нет литературы, прогуглите :  std::basic_ios::clear().

Comment: Запомните этот сайт: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот вы прочли все, что могли. Произошла **ошибка** чтения, `while` завершился.

Поток оставля в состоянии **ошибки** - установлены соответствующие биты (ну, или конец файла, или неверный формат - что там на самом деле произошло).

Работать с таким потоком нельзя - функции будут просто вылетать: состояние потока не позволяет ничего делать.

`clear` "чистит" это состояние, сбрасывая все установленные флаги ошибки...